# Twitter module does not work in drupal site

Tags: drupal-7

I have installed twitter in my drupal site. But when I tried to configure setting. It goes to the - configuration > webservices > No setting.

Do I need to set permission for the or what else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
By using twitter card I solved issue
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed Oauth_common module along with twitter module.

Next step is to clear cache and check if the module is enabled properly. If you still not find the link then clear the cache (menu specifically) and check it.

Always use superadmin for enabling / disabling of your modules or use drush commands.

Comment: I have installed the Oauth as Oauth_common is deprecated onward.
Module is enabled properly.

Comment: Did you navigate to {your-domain}/admin/config/services/twitter/settings and also fill the OAUTH SETTINGS section to link your account.

Comment: I can get its setting. Even module is enabled.

Comment: Add installed both module manually. So by drush commands. Just need to enable or disable module or download module by drush too.